# How can I save an EEM file on a Fluoromax4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, water, software, spectrophotometry, fluorescence

I'm trying to run excitation-emission matrices on some water samples, but I'm running into some software issues that the manuals aren't helpful for. In order to use R studio to extract my data, I need to save my output as a .eem file, but I don't see how to do that.

When I try to save my matrix, the only option I get is an .spc, which it doesn't even let me do that - I get an error saying I need to change my matrix into a worksheet. I can't even figure out how to do that.

Is it saving these eems automatically somewhere I can't find? All I've been able to do is save an ASCII version of my data, which isn't a format the eemR package lets me import.

Hardware: Horiba Fluoromax 4

Software: Horiba FluorEscence, R studio eemR, Matlab drEEM

Thanks

Comment: I have never used the software, but most spectroscopy softwares have an option to extract data as .csv files. See if you can do that and then convert the csv to eem, or read the csv with R studio. As .csv is almost an universal data format, most softwares should be able to read it too.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti thank you; I have the .csv, but the specific matlab/R packages I'm using to analyze the data work best/only with the proprietary .eem files from different fluorometers - you specify the model you have and give it the file and it knows what to do from there - trying to go around this with a csv would make the process more time consuming. Starting to think it'd be faster than waiting on Horiba support, though.

Comment: Is this useful? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hyperSpec/versions/0.98-20140523/topics/read.spc